# Writing expression in polars-lazy in rust

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I need to write my own expression in polars_lazy. Based on my understanding from the source code I need to write a function that returns Expr::Function. The problem is that in order to construct an object of this type, an object of type FunctionOptions must be provided. The caveat is that this class is public but the members are pub(crate) and thus outside of the create one cannot construct such an object.
Are there ways around this?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the Rust API for polars is not well documented enough to really use yet. Although the other answer and comments mention `apply` and `map`, they don't mention how or the trade-offs. I hope this answer prompts others to correct me with the "right" way to do things.

So first, here's how to use `apply` on lazy dataframe, even though lazy dataframes don't take `apply` directly as a method as eager ones do, and mutating in-place:

```
// not sure how you'd find this type easily from apply documentation
let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::UInt32);
// this mutates two in place
let lf = lf.with_column(col("two").apply(str_to_len, o));
```

And here's how to use it while not mutating the source column and adding a new output column instead:

```
let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::UInt32);
// this adds new column len, two is unchanged
let lf = lf.with_column(col("two").alias("len").apply(str_to_len, o));
```

With the `str_to_len` looking like:

```
fn str_to_len(str_val: Series) -> Result<Series> {
    let x = str_val
        .utf8()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        // your actual custom function would be in this map
        .map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.map(|name: &str| name.len() as u32))
        .collect::<UInt32Chunked>();
    Ok(x.into_series())
}
```

Note that it takes `Series` rather than `&Series` and wraps in `Result`.

With a regular (non-lazy) dataframe, `apply` still mutates but doesn't require `with_column`:

```
df.apply("two", str_to_len).expect("applied");
```

Whereas eager/non-lazy's `with_column` doesn't require `apply`:

```
// the fn we use to make the column names it too
df.with_column(str_to_len(df.column("two").expect("has two"))).expect("with_column");
```

And `str_to_len` has slightly different signature:

```
fn str_to_len(str_val: &Series) -> Series {
    let mut x = str_val
        .utf8()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.map(|name: &str| name.len() as u32))
        .collect::<UInt32Chunked>();
    // NB. this is naming the chunked array, before we even get to a series
    x.rename("len");
    x.into_series()
}
```

I know there's reasons to have lazy and eager operate differently, but I wish the Rust documentation made this easier to figure out.

Comment: Great examples, thanks! Is there need/functionality to parallelize apply/map ?

Comment: ie you could ido `use polars::export::rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;` and then replace .into_iter() with .par_ier() ... do you think such parallisation would be benefitial for performance?

Comment: Could you explain why to use map twice in `map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.map(|name: &str| name.len() as u32))`?   Why not `map(|opt_name: Option<&str>| opt_name.unwrap().len())`?

Comment: Re @Crispy13 - I don't want to throw via `unwrap` unwrapping a `None`, so the inner `map` protects me from that. Could instead use `filter_map` too. @Anatoly Bugakov - what parallelization helps depends on what work your function is doing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're meant to directly construct `Expr`s. Instead, you can use functions like `polars_lazy::dsl::col()` and `polars_lazy::dsl::lit()` to create expressions, then use methods on `Expr` to build up the expression. Several of those methods, such as `map()` and `apply()`, will give you an `Expr::Function`.

Comment: But I need an expression that is not available in polars_lazy. A have an utf8 column and need to do some custom massaging that cannot be obtained by combining existing expressions.

Comment: I have 'partially' solved this by using eager but it would be better to do it in lazy.

Comment: As the awnser correctly states. You can use the apply expression to apply a custom closure over your string data.