# How to apply a function to multiple columns of a polars DataFrame in Rust

Tags: dataframe, rust, apply, rust-polars

I'd like to apply a user-define function which takes a few inputs (corresponding some columns in a polars DataFrame) to some columns of a polars DataFrame in Rust. The pattern that I'm using is as below. I wonder is this the best practice?

```
fn my_filter_func(col1: &Series, col2: &Series, col2: &Series) -> ReturnType {
    let it = (0..n).map(|i| {
        let col1 = match col.get(i) {
            AnyValue::UInt64(val) => val,
            _ => panic!("Wrong type of col1!"),
        };
        // similar for col2 and col3
        // apply user-defined function to col1, col2 and col3
    }
    // convert it to a collection of the required type
}
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386839/writing-expression-in-polars-lazy-in-rust

Answer (score 5):

You can downcast the `Series` to the proper type you want to iterate over, and then use rust iterators to apply your logic.

```rust
fn my_black_box_function(a: f32, b: f32) -> f32 {
    // do something
    a
}

fn apply_multiples(col_a: &Series, col_b: &Series) -> Float32Chunked {
    match (col_a.dtype(), col_b.dtype()) {
        (DataType::Float32, DataType::Float32) => {
            let a = col_a.f32().unwrap();
            let b = col_b.f32().unwrap();

            a.into_iter()
                .zip(b.into_iter())
                .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
                    (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(my_black_box_function(a, b)),
                    _ => None,
                })
                .collect()
        }
        _ => panic!("unpexptected dtypes"),
    }
}
```

### Lazy API

You don't have to leave the lazy API to be able to access `my_black_box_function`.

We can collect the columns we want to apply in a `Struct` data type and then apply a closure over that `Series`.

```rust
fn apply_multiples(lf: LazyFrame) -> Result<DataFrame> {
    df![
        "a" => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        "b" => [3.0, 5.1, 0.3]
    ]?
    .lazy()
    .select([concat_lst(["col_a", "col_b"]).map(
        |s| {
            let ca = s.struct_()?;

            let b = ca.field_by_name("col_a")?;
            let a = ca.field_by_name("col_b")?;
            let a = a.f32()?;
            let b = b.f32()?;

            let out: Float32Chunked = a
                .into_iter()
                .zip(b.into_iter())
                .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
                    (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(my_black_box_function(a, b)),
                    _ => None,
                })
                .collect();

            Ok(out.into_series())
        },
        GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float32),
    )])
    .collect()
}
```

Comment: Does the lazy API loads rows when needed or does it try to load the whole file at once? It seems to me that columns are loaded and converted to ChunkedArrays, which means that all rows are loaded into memory?

Comment: I don't think concat_lst is defined anywhere

Comment: Not all feature flags are activated by default. It does exist, but you need to activate the `list` feature.

Comment: If the whole file is loaded into memory any way, there's really no advantage of using LazyFrame APIs in this case, right?

Comment: Your question does not mention a file. That would be another question.

Comment: Second example returns an error Err(SchemaMisMatch(Owned("Series of dtype: List(Float64) != Struct",),),)

Comment: Instead of concat_lst need to use as_struct

Comment: Yep, need to use `as_struct(["col_a", "col_b"])` and also enable feature `dtype-struct`

Comment: Probably the author meant the function `concat_list` (https://docs.rs/polars/0.35.4/polars/prelude/fn.concat_list.html), at least on polars version 0.35.4. It also does not work well when both original columns are lists, because they get flattened into a single list.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found working for me is with map_multiple(my understanding - this to be used if no groupby/agg) or apply_multiple(my understanding - whenerver you have groupby/agg). Alternatively, you could also use map_many or apply_many. See below.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars::df;

fn main() {
    let df = df! [
        "names" => ["a", "b", "a"],
        "values" => [1, 2, 3],
        "values_nulls" => [Some(1), None, Some(3)],
        "new_vals" => [Some(1.0), None, Some(3.0)]
    ].unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", df);

    //df.try_apply("values_nulls", |s: &Series| s.cast(&DataType::Float64)).unwrap();

    let df = df.lazy()
        .groupby([col("names")])
        .agg( [
            total_delta_sens().sum()
        ]
        );

    println!("{:?}", df.collect());
}

pub fn total_delta_sens () -> Expr {
    let s: &mut [Expr] = &mut [col("values"), col("values_nulls"),  col("new_vals")];

    fn sum_fa(s: &mut [Series])->Result<Series>{
        let mut ss = s[0].cast(&DataType::Float64).unwrap().fill_null(FillNullStrategy::Zero).unwrap().clone();
        for i in 1..s.len(){
            ss = ss.add_to(&s[i].cast(&DataType::Float64).unwrap().fill_null(FillNullStrategy::Zero).unwrap()).unwrap();
        }
        Ok(ss) 
    }

    let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64);
    map_multiple(sum_fa, s, o)
}
```

Here total_delta_sens  is just a wrapper function for convenience. You don't have to use it.You can do directly this within your .agg([]) or .with_columns([]) :
`lit::<f64>(0.0).map_many(sum_fa, &[col("norm"), col("uniform")], o)`

Inside sum_fa you can as Richie already mentioned downcast to ChunkedArray and .iter() or even .par_iter()
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

This example uses Rust Polars version = "0.30"

Apply the same function on the selected columns:

```
lazyframe
.with_columns([
    cols(col_name1, col_name2, ..., col_nameN)
   .apply(|series| 
       some_function(series), 
       GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64)
   )
]);
```

Or apply many functions to many columns with a much more flexible and powerful method:

```
lazyframe
.with_columns([
    some_function1(col_name1, col_name2, ..., col_nameN), 
    some_function2(col_name1, col_name2, ..., col_nameM),
    some_functionN(col_name1, col_name2, ..., col_nameZ),
]);
```

The Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.30", features = [
    "lazy", # Lazy API
    "round_series", # round underlying float types of Series
] }
```

And the main() function:

```
use std::error::Error;

use polars::{
    prelude::*,
    datatypes::DataType,
};

fn main()-> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    let dataframe01: DataFrame = df!(
        "integers"  => &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        "float64 A" => [23.654, 0.319, 10.0049, 89.01999, -3.41501, 52.0766],
        "options"   => [Some(28), Some(300), None, Some(2), Some(-30), None],
        "float64 B" => [9.9999, 0.399, 10.0061, 89.0105, -3.4331, 52.099999],
    )?;

    println!("dataframe01: {dataframe01}\n");

    // let selected: Vec<&str> = vec!["float64 A", "float64 B"];

    // Example 1:
    // Format only the columns with float64
    // input: two columns --> output: two columns

    let lazyframe: LazyFrame = dataframe01
        .lazy()
        .with_columns([
            //cols(selected)
            all()
            .apply(|series| 
                round_float64_columns(series, 2),
                GetOutput::same_type()
             )
         ]);

    let dataframe02: DataFrame = lazyframe.clone().collect()?;

    println!("dataframe02: {dataframe02}\n");

    let series_a: Series = Series::new("float64 A", &[23.65, 0.32, 10.00, 89.02, -3.42, 52.08]);
    let series_b: Series = Series::new("float64 B", &[10.00,  0.4, 10.01, 89.01, -3.43, 52.1]);

    assert_eq!(dataframe02.column("float64 A")?, &series_a);
    assert_eq!(dataframe02.column("float64 B")?, &series_b);

    // Example 2:
    // input1: two columns --> output: one new column
    // input2: one column  --> output: one new column
    // input3: two columns --> output: one new column

    let lazyframe: LazyFrame = lazyframe
        .with_columns([
            apuracao1("float64 A", "float64 B", "New Column 1"),
            apuracao2("float64 A", "New Column 2"),
            (col("integers") * lit(10) + col("options")).alias("New Column 3"),
         ]);

    println!("dataframe03: {}\n", lazyframe.collect()?);

    Ok(())
}

pub fn round_float64_columns(series: Series, decimals: u32) -> Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {
    match series.dtype() {
        DataType::Float64 => Ok(Some(series.round(decimals)?)),
        _ => Ok(Some(series))
    }
}

fn apuracao1(name_a: &str, name_b: &str, new: &str) -> Expr {
    (col(name_a) * col(name_b) / lit(100))
    //.over("some_group")
    .alias(new)
}

fn apuracao2(name_a: &str, new: &str) -> Expr {
    (lit(10) * col(name_a) - lit(2))
    //.over("some_group")
    .alias(new)
}
```

The output:

```
dataframe01: shape: (6, 4)
┌──────────┬───────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ integers ┆ float64 A ┆ options ┆ float64 B │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i32      ┆ f64       ┆ i32     ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 23.654    ┆ 28      ┆ 9.9999    │
│ 2        ┆ 0.319     ┆ 300     ┆ 0.399     │
│ 3        ┆ 10.0049   ┆ null    ┆ 10.0061   │
│ 4        ┆ 89.01999  ┆ 2       ┆ 89.0105   │
│ 5        ┆ -3.41501  ┆ -30     ┆ -3.4331   │
│ 6        ┆ 52.0766   ┆ null    ┆ 52.099999 │
└──────────┴───────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

dataframe02: shape: (6, 4)
┌──────────┬───────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ integers ┆ float64 A ┆ options ┆ float64 B │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i32      ┆ f64       ┆ i32     ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 23.65     ┆ 28      ┆ 10.0      │
│ 2        ┆ 0.32      ┆ 300     ┆ 0.4       │
│ 3        ┆ 10.0      ┆ null    ┆ 10.01     │
│ 4        ┆ 89.02     ┆ 2       ┆ 89.01     │
│ 5        ┆ -3.42     ┆ -30     ┆ -3.43     │
│ 6        ┆ 52.08     ┆ null    ┆ 52.1      │
└──────────┴───────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

dataframe03: shape: (6, 7)
┌──────────┬───────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ integers ┆ float64 A ┆ options ┆ float64 B ┆ New Column 1 ┆ New Column 2 ┆ New Column 3 │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ i32      ┆ f64       ┆ i32     ┆ f64       ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ i32          │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 23.65     ┆ 28      ┆ 10.0      ┆ 2.365        ┆ 234.5        ┆ 38           │
│ 2        ┆ 0.32      ┆ 300     ┆ 0.4       ┆ 0.00128      ┆ 1.2          ┆ 320          │
│ 3        ┆ 10.0      ┆ null    ┆ 10.01     ┆ 1.001        ┆ 98.0         ┆ null         │
│ 4        ┆ 89.02     ┆ 2       ┆ 89.01     ┆ 79.236702    ┆ 888.2        ┆ 42           │
│ 5        ┆ -3.42     ┆ -30     ┆ -3.43     ┆ 0.117306     ┆ -36.2        ┆ 20           │
│ 6        ┆ 52.08     ┆ null    ┆ 52.1      ┆ 27.13368     ┆ 518.8        ┆ null         │
└──────────┴───────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant that I built based on @ritchie46's answer. It's not as elegant and less efficient memory-wise (and probably also compute-wise), but maybe it helps understanding the big picture.

The UDF (user-defined function) concatenates a string column with an integer column.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

pub fn udf(series: Series) ->  Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {
    let mut result: Vec<String> = vec![];
    for struct_ in series.iter() {
        let mut iter = struct_._iter_struct_av();
        let first = iter.next().unwrap();
        let second = iter.next().unwrap();

        let a = first.get_str().unwrap();
        let b = second.try_extract::<i32>().unwrap();

        // Here you have your individual values
        println!("{:?}, {:?}",a, b);

        let concat = format!("{}-{}", a, b);
        result.push(concat);
    }
    let output: ChunkedArray<Utf8Type> = result.into_iter().collect(); 
    return Ok(Some(output.into_series()));
}


fn main() {
    let stub_output_type = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64);
    let mut df = df![
        "a" => ["x", "y"],
        "b" => [1, 2],
    ].unwrap();

    df = df.lazy().with_columns(
        [
            as_struct(vec![col("a"), col("b")])
                .apply(|s| udf(s), stub_output_type)
                .alias("new_column")
        ]
    ).collect().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", df);
}
```

And to compile, use this Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "explore-rust-polars"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
polars = {version = "0.35.4", features = ["lazy", "dtype-struct"]}
```

The output:

```
"x", 1
"y", 2
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ new_column │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str ┆ i32 ┆ str        │
╞═════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   ┆ x-1        │
│ y   ┆ 2   ┆ y-2        │
└─────┴─────┴────────────┘
```