# How to write a findInterval function using Rust?

Tags: rust

The function `findInterval(x, v)` takes x and v as inputs, and both of them are vectors. The function iterates the x vector and compares its values with the v vector. If the value from the x vector is less than the value from the first index in the v vector it will return a Null Value. If the values are greater or equal to the values from the v vector it will return the index of the vector until the condition is not met for that index, and will move on to the next index.

I am taking as an example the logic from [R Reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html).

**Example:**

**Inputs:**

```
let x = vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
let v = vec![5, 10, 15];
```

**Expected Output:**

`[Null, Null, Null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

In the expected output, I want `Null or Na`. The purpose for that is that it doesn't take into account when you try to index another vector. As seen in [R Reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html).

**My Solution:**

```
pub fn find_interval(x: Vec<u32>, v: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    let n = x.len();
    let m = v.len();
    let mut c = 0;
    let i = 0;
    let mut result = Vec::new();

    for j in 0..m {
        for i in 0..n {
            if x[i] < v[j] {
                result.push(c);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if x[i] >= v[j] {
            c += 1;
            result.push(c);
        }
    }
    return result
}


fn main(){
    let x = vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
    let v = vec![5, 10, 15];

    let result: Vec<u32> = find_interval(x,v);

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The purpose of this function is to use it for the function below:

```
pub fn volatility_default_spread_f(x: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<f64>{

    if (!x.is_nan()){
        let mut y = Vec::new();
        let spreads = vec![0.0099,0.0165,0.02068,0.031625,0.066125,0.083375,0.100625];
        let lcoverage = vec![0,0.25,0.4,0.65,0.75,0.9,1.0];
        let result = find_interval(x, lcoverage);
    
        for &index in &result {
            if index < spreads.len() {
                y.push(spreads[index]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    
    } else {
        let y = 0.0188;
    } 
    return y
}
```

Comment: Are the vectors always monotonically increasing from the first to the last element?

Comment: Yes, the values in the vectors are always increasing monotonically from the first to the last element.

Answer (score 2):

The logic of this sequence is easy enough to write into a proper iterator. We can even make the iterator generic over its input!  To start with, let's define the iterator type:

```
struct FindIntervalIterator<T, U, UI> {
    /// Iterator for "x" values.
    x: T,
    /// Iterator for "v" values.
    v: U,
    /// Current index into "v".
    index: usize,
    /// Current "v" value, None if "v" is out of values.
    currentv: Option<UI>,
}
```

Now let's implement `Iterator` on this type.  We have to bound on `T` and `U` being iterators, and we additionally need to bound on `T`'s item type that it can be relationally compared to `U`'s item type.  We start with this:

```
impl<T, U, TI, UI> Iterator for FindIntervalIterator<T, U, UI>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = TI>,
    U: Iterator<Item = UI>,
    TI: PartialOrd<UI>,
{
    // TODO
}
```

As indicated in your question, the first items in the sequence can be "null" which tells us that the type of item produced by this iterator should be `Option<X>` -- so what should `X` be?  In your code, it's `u32`.  However, array and vector indices in Rust are `usize`, so it makes sense to use that here.  We can't reasonably enforce that it's the same type as `TI` or `TU`, at least not without some extra bounds on what those types could be.  Therefore, we will go with `Option<usize>`.

Additionally, we will implement `Iterator::size_hint` by delegating directly to the "x" iterator's implementation, as we will always produce exactly the same number of elements as that iterator.  This allows consumers of our iterator to be more efficient.  For example, if the results are `collect()`ed into a `Vec`, the destination `Vec` can be created with the correct capacity to avoid reallocations as it is populated.

```
impl<T, U, TI, UI> Iterator for FindIntervalIterator<T, U, UI>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = TI>,
    U: Iterator<Item = UI>,
    TI: PartialOrd<UI>,
{
    type Item = Option<usize>;

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.x.size_hint()
    }

    // TODO
}
```

Now we just have to implement `Iterator::next` with the desired logic.

By now you've probably noticed that `self.index` is `usize`, but we need to return `Option<usize>`.  I did this for the sake of simplicity.  By starting at 0, we can obtain the desired value by [subtracting 1 with an underflow check](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_sub); that is, `self.index.checked_sub(1)` returns `Option<usize>` and produces exactly the value you want.

Putting this all together into code, we arrive at this implementation:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    let x = self.x.next()?;

    while let Some(v) = &self.currentv {
        if &x >= v {
            self.index += 1;
            self.currentv = self.v.next();
        }
    }

    Some(self.index.checked_sub(1))
}
```

Finally, we need a function to create the iterator:

```
fn find_interval<T, U, TI, UI>(x: T, v: U) -> FindIntervalIterator<T::IntoIter, U::IntoIter, UI>
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = TI>,
    U: IntoIterator<Item = UI>,
{
    let x = x.into_iter();
    let mut v = v.into_iter();

    FindIntervalIterator {
        currentv: v.next(),
        x,
        v,
        index: 0,
    }
}
```

Finally, we can test that it works correctly:

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
    let v = vec![5, 10, 15];

    let intervals: Vec<_> = find_interval(x, v).collect();

    assert_eq!(
        intervals,
        vec![
            None,
            None,
            None,
            Some(0),
            Some(0),
            Some(0),
            Some(0),
            Some(0),
            Some(1),
            Some(1),
            Some(1),
            Some(1),
            Some(1),
            Some(2),
            Some(2),
            Some(2),
            Some(2),
        ]
    );

    let x = vec![0.3234234];
    let v = vec![0.0, 0.25, 0.4];

    let intervals: Vec<_> = find_interval(x, v).collect();

    assert_eq!(intervals, vec![Some(1)]);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=983aaf0c624e0f04655381682fa035c3))

This is a bit more complicated than a simple function that accepts two `Vec`s and returns another.  However, it has a few advantages:

- It will work for *any* pair of iterators where the item types form a partial order.  In other words, you can use it with more than `u32`.  You can use other built-in numeric types, or even non-primitive types!
- You can evaluate the iterator lazily, avoiding allocating a `Vec` to hold the results.

  - However, you can still `collect` the iterator into a `Vec` if you need to, and it's very likely that an optimized build will inline all of the iterator's code as though you'd written the function as you originally designed it.  In fact, it can only perform *better* than the example code you provide because the `size_hint` implementation allows `collect` to avoid reallocations when the size of the `x` iterator is known!
- You can use any of the other `Iterator` utility combinators with the custom iterator.
- Building a proper generic iterator may make it easier to reason about the code that produces the sequence, as it boils the types down to the bare minimum traits they need to implement.

Comment: After trying this function out, I was able to find that there was a mistake. If the first value from the vector X is greater or equal to the value of any index in vector V. It always returns the index 0, instead of returning the other index. For example let x = vec![0.3234234], and v = vec![0.0, 0.25, 0.4]. It should return Some(1), but instead, it returns 0.0. How could we fix this issue?

Comment: @CarlosArias Good point. I will add that as a test case and fix it; it's because an `if` should be a `while`.

Comment: @CarlosArias I've fixed this bug. The fix makes the code a bit cleaner, even.

Comment: thanks for the help. Also, if you would like to make this function as an expression how should I proceed?

Comment: @CarlosArias I'm not sure what you mean by "make this function as an expression."

Comment: For example as seen in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398548/how-can-i-create-a-new-column-in-a-dataframe-by-using-a-function-in-rust-polars

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me how you want to achieve "Null" for the first interval, but maybe this solution will suffice, it will return `isize` values, with `-1` meaning the first interval. The function uses a basic `std::iter::scan` to produce an iterator of values, computed with some accumulated value. In our case, the accumulated value is the current interval index.

```
pub fn find_interval(values: Vec<u32>, borders: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<isize> {
    values.iter()
        .scan(-1, |interval, &v| {
            if *interval + 1 < borders.len() as isize && 
                v >= borders[(*interval + 1) as usize] {
                *interval += 1
            }
            Some(*interval)
        })
        .collect()
}


fn main(){
    let x = vec![2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
    let v = vec![5, 10, 15];

    let result = find_interval(x,v);

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```