# Insert multiple calculated columns with identical calculation at once in rust polars?

Tags: rust-polars

I have a polars dataframe in rust with multiple columns containing stats and I need to add new calculated columns based on them with identical calculations.

Obviously I could do one expression with an .alias() for each and wrap it in one with_columns-statement, but I want it not have such boilerplate and be a bit more elegant than that.

Suppose an initial df with records of visits at a doctor looks like this:

| id | patient | date | blood pressure | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | joe | 2019-11-29 | 130 | 140 |
| 1 | jim | 2019-11-29 | 99 | 145 |
| 2 | michael | 2019-11-29 | 104 | 110 |
| 3 | sarah | 2019-11-30 | 96 | 98 |
| 4 | joe | 2019-11-30 | 115 | 130 |

Now I'd like to relate blood pressure and weight *on average* (EDIT: just as an example, I know there's a built-in function to calculate mean/avg):

| id | patient | date | blood pressure | weight | blood pressure (avg) | weight (avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | joe | 2019-11-29 | 130 | 140 | 130 | 140 |
| 1 | jim | 2019-11-29 | 99 | 145 | 99 | 145 |
| 2 | michael | 2019-11-29 | 104 | 110 | 104 | 110 |
| 3 | sarah | 2019-11-30 | 96 | 98 | 96 | 98 |
| 4 | joe | 2019-11-30 | 115 | 130 | 122.5 | 135 |

[Building on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72372821/how-to-apply-a-function-to-multiple-columns-of-a-polars-dataframe-in-rust) I played around with code blocks like this, however wasn't able to properly create more than one new column with aliases built on their previous name.

```
use polars::prelude::{cols, DataFrame, DataType, GetOutput}:

df = df
    .lazy()
    .with_columns([cols([
        "weight",
        "blood pressure",
    ])
    .map(
        |series| {
            // calculate average
        },
        GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64),
    ))
    .alias("blood pressure (avg)"])  // this should be automatically evaluated
                                     // from the list of columns specified in cols()
    .collect()?;
```

Using polars 0.26.1.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.rs/polars/0.26.1/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.suffix

Answer (score 0):

you can use `name().suffix()` method for that:

```
df = df
    .lazy()
    .with_columns([
        cols(["weight", "blood pressure"])
            .map(
                |series| {
                    // calculate average
                },
                GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float64)
            )
            .name().suffix(" (avg)"),
    ])
    .collect()?;
```

result

```
shape: (5, 7)
╭─────┬─────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────────╮
│ id  ┆ patient ┆ data       ┆ blood pressure ┆ weight ┆ weight (avg) ┆ blood pressure (avg) │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---                  │
│ i32 ┆ str     ┆ str        ┆ i32            ┆ i32    ┆ i32          ┆ i32                  │
╞═════╪═════════╪════════════╪════════════════╪════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ joe     ┆ 2019-11-29 ┆ 130            ┆ 140    ┆ 140          ┆ 130                  │
│ 2   ┆ jim     ┆ 2019-11-29 ┆ 99             ┆ 145    ┆ 145          ┆ 99                   │
│ 3   ┆ michael ┆ 2019-11-29 ┆ 104            ┆ 110    ┆ 110          ┆ 104                  │
│ 4   ┆ sarah   ┆ 2019-11-30 ┆ 96             ┆ 98     ┆ 98           ┆ 96                   │
│ 5   ┆ joe     ┆ 2019-11-30 ┆ 115            ┆ 130    ┆ 130          ┆ 115                  │
╰─────┴─────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────────╯
```